# Creating a histogram over a Power BI measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, histogram, visualization, powerbi-desktop

Since Microsoft decided to deprecate the Histogram visualization in Power BI it became a problem to visualize distributions in this application.

I solved this problem in the case where the histogram is over a table column: using a clustered column chart with the value as the X axis and the count as the Y axis (It is also possible to add range bins to group together different values).

However, if I have a measure, this approach will not work. For example, If I have a table of movie ratings (with columns 'movieId', 'userId', and 'userMovieRating') I don't know how to create a histogram of the average ratings for each movie. If I try the approach that was described above, Power BI will not even let me use the measure in the X axis.

sample data:

| movieId | userId | rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| m1 | u1 | 5 |
| m1 | u2 | 3 |
| m2 | u1 | 2 |
| m2 | u3 | 4 |
| m2 | u4 | 3 |
| m3 | u2 | 3 |
| m3 | u3 | 3 |
| m3 | u5 | 3 |

expected output:

| Average rating | number of Movies |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |

Can you suggest a way to achieve this without creating additional tables?

Comment: Can  you supply some sample data and expected outcome?

Comment: Done. I added the sample table. Of course, my actual data is much larger.

Comment: I'll show you now. You will have to create another table but this is normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

movies table looks like this as per your sample data.

[image]

Create a measure as follows:

```
Ave Rating = AVERAGE(movies[rating])
```

Create a new disconnected table as follows:

```
Average Ratings = 
VAR maxRating = MAXX(VALUES(movies[movieId]), [Ave Rating])
RETURN GENERATESERIES(0,maxRating,1)
```

which produces the following:

[image]

You need to use generate series for a proper histogram as some averages (0,1,2) will have a count of zero and you want these to show too.

Create a column chart. On the x axis, add the column from your newly created table ensuring show all values is selected.

On the y axis, add the following measure:

```
Measure = 

VAR cursor = SELECTEDVALUE('Average Ratings'[Value])

VAR segment = 
FILTER(
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        SUMMARIZE(movies, movies[movieId]),
        "@aveRating", [Ave Rating]
    ),
    [@aveRating] = cursor
)
    
RETURN COUNTROWS(segment)
```

Finished result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure I understand everything you did here, so I'll need to dig into the syntax of each part of the solution. I want to make sure I understand one thing: In your new table there are only integer numbers. Will your measure also capture movies with a non-integer average rating such as 3.5 or 4.29?

Comment: No, you will need to change the formula to step at however many decimal places you want. Alternatively, if you don't care about showing averages with zero count, just do a VALUES() instead.

Comment: Will this work with filters? Let's assume I try to filter the visualization to consider only new movies. Will this filter affect the visual? In other words, is the "SUMMARIZE(movies, movies[movieId])" expression influenced by the filter or will it always take all movies into consideration?

Comment: Yes, it will work with slicers. That is the whole point of using a measure and a disconnected table.